# MySQL: How do I order the results depending on if they are also present in other tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

**MySQL (simplified tables)**

table_1

```
+----+-------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+
| 1  | test  |
+----+-------+
| 2  | test  |
+----+-------+
| 3  | test  |
+----+-------+
```

table_2

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
+----+
```

table_3

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
+----+
| 3  |
+----+
```

**PHP**

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT t1.id FROM table_1 AS t1 WHERE MATCH(t1.title) AGAINST ('test' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
```

What I want to do now is:

a) If the `id` is included in `table_2` OR `table_3` it should be ranked higher than if it's only present in `table_1`

b) If the `id` is included in `table_2` AND `table_3` it should be ranked even higher

So, the output should be:

```
1, 3, 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select table_1.id, 
  (case
  when max(table_2.id) is not null AND max(table_3.id) is not null then 0
  when max(table_2.id) is not null OR max(table_3.id) is not null then 1
  else 2
  end) rank
from table_1 left outer join table_2 on
   table_1.id = table_2.id left outer join table_3 on
   table_1.id = table_3.id
group by table_1.id
order by rank
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.id 
FROM table_1 a
LEFT JOIN table_2 b ON b.id = a.id
LEFT JOIN table_3 c ON c.id = a.id
ORDER BY
    b.id IS NOT NULL AND c.id IS NOT NULL DESC,
    b.id IS NOT NULL OR c.id IS NOT NULL DESC
```

You can ad subsequent orderings of what to do when multiple entries have the same priority